# Implementing greater-than sudoku solver in Prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd

How to implement [greater-than sudoku](https://plus.maths.org/content/puzzle-page-77) solver in Prolog using clpfd? I have trouble figuring out how to add those greater-than constraints to regular sudoku solver.

Comment: Please provide some code where you show your attempt

Comment: Btw, i've seen the photo on the link and i've seen no pattern. So i think you had to add each constraint by hand

Answer (score 1):

Simply put every square in a finite domain with the digits 1 to 9 and emit a #< constraint on each edge.